# Get mysql data from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables like this:

Table 1

```
ID | COST |
1  | 601  |
```

Table 2

```
   ID | COST |
   1  | 1000 |
```

I want to select data from this two tables. How to do this? I want output like this

```
[
  Table1 => [... data],
  Table2 => [...data]
]
```

Comment: You should also include any attempts you've made. We gladly help you fix issues with your existing code, but we're not going to write it all for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the rows from both the tables  you could use union all

```
 select  cost
 from  table1 
 union all  
 select cost 
 from table2
```